# The Ax-Kochen isomorphism theorem and the continuum hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, local-fields, diophantine-geometry

Let's recall that:

(1): The **Ax-Kochen principle** says that if $\mathcal{U}$ is a non-principal ultrafilter over prime numbers, then $\prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{F}_p((t)) \equiv \prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{Q}_p$.

(2): The **Ax-Kochen isomorphism theorem** says that if $CH$ (the Continuum hypothesis) holds, and if $\mathcal{U}$ is a non-principal ultrafilter over prime numbers, then $\prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{F}_p((t)) \cong \prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{Q}_p$.

It is easily seen that (1) implies (2), as under $CH$, both of the structures $\prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{F}_p((t))$ and $ \prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{Q}_p$ have size $\aleph_1$ and are saturated, hence are isomorphic.

On the other hand (2) implies (1) by a forcing argument and absoluteness. To see this, let $V$ be an arbitrary model of $ZFC$ and let $\mathcal{U}$ be a non-principal ultrafilter over prime numbers. Let $G$ be $Add(\aleph_1, 1)$-generic over $V$. Then $V$ and $V[G]$ have the same reals, in particular $\mathcal{U}$ remains an ultrafilter in $V[G]$. Also $CH$ holds in $V[G]$, so $V[G]\models\prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{F}_p((t)) \cong \prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{Q}_p$. Hence $V[G]\models\prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{F}_p((t)) \equiv \prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{Q}_p$, and by absoluteness $\prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{F}_p((t)) \equiv \prod_{\mathbb{U}} \mathbb{Q}_p$ holds in $V$.

In [Vive la différence II. The Ax-Kochen isomorphism theorem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02758648), Shelah has shown $CH$ can not be removed from the Ax-Kochen isomorphism theorem.

Motivated by these results, I would like to ask the following:

> **Question** Is the Ax-Kochen isomorphism theorem consistent with the negation of Continuum hypothesis?

Comment: I'm confused: if Shelah showed that $\mathsf{CH}$ can't be removed from the theorem, then that means the theorem isn't consistent with $\neg\mathsf{CH}$? Am I missing something?

Comment: It is a consistency result, there is a model of $ZFC$ in which CH fails and the isomorphism theorem does not hold. It does not say that the failure of CH implies the negation of the theorem.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've thought about model theory, but can this be addressed by techniques of Ellentuck and Rucker "Martin's Axiom and Saturated Models"?  They show that under MA there is an ultrafilter $F$ on $\omega$ such that the $F$-ultrapower of any countable structure is saturated.

Comment: Also interesting : is the absoluteness of the result of Moloney mentioned in Shelah's paper still open?

Comment: @ToddEisworth Thanks for introducing this nice reference. However, it does not answer the question, as for the isomorphism theorem, we require it holds for all  non-principal ultrafilter over prime numbers

Comment: @PaulLarson Yes, I've seen this question in Shelah's paper as well, but have no ideas for it.

Comment: Drat!  I was hoping to be able to cite Rudy Rucker's mathematics!

Comment: @MohammadGolshani right, I interpreted too literally the "$\mathsf{CH}$ can't be removed" part (although in a strict reading, "$\mathsf{CH}$ can't be removed" could read as "$\mathsf{CH}$ is necessary" which would literally mean "the Ax--Cochen isomorphism theorem implies $\mathsf{CH}$"). Anyway, the question is really interesting.